# Desktops move to wrong displays upon wake

Tags: display, hdmi, desktop

I'm running Sonoma with 2 external displays, one via HDMI, and one via USB-C. The USB-C display has 3 virtual desktops, and the HDMI one a single virtual desktop.
The vast majority of the time (every time?) I plug in the displays into my computer, the virtual desktops are on the HDMI display, and the USB-C one has a single desktop, forcing me to move them via drag and drop before I run `moom` to move the windows back to the right desktop.

How do I make sure the desktops are on the correct displays when I plug in the displays?